# How split a string into all possible consecutive combinations about a particular delimiter

Tags: java

I want to create all possible consecutive combinations about a particular delimiter from a given String.

For example:

`String s = "a\\b\\c\\d"` and `String delimiter = "\\\\"`

Using

```
`String[] split = s.split(delimiter);`
```

returns

```
 `{"a","b","c","d"}`
```

But I want to get:

`{"a","b","c","d","a\\b","b\\c","c\\d","a\\b\\c","b\\c\\d"};`

How can I do this? Not necessarily using split

Comment: Based on which condition you need to split.

Comment: It looks like you want to conditionally split.  But, what about cases longer than 3 tokens?  What would you expect from `"A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\G\\H"`, or longer? Just singletons and pairs?  Sequences of all lengths shorter than the input?

Comment: Not possible with regex I suppose but you can split with `\\` then you can generate all the possible combination

Comment: @ Arun Prasat i need split "\\"

Comment: @ YCF_L  How can i do this??

Comment: @ azurefrog Different lines, but all are divided \\

Comment: So the input format is always *strictly* `"A\\B\\C"`?  Then just take the `[A,B,C]` array you've already got and add `"A\\B"` and `"B\\C"` to it, like @YCF_L suggested.

Comment: about the generation of combination I guess this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515516/enumeration-combinations-of-k-elements-using-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CombinationSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> split = split("a\\b\\c\\d", "\\\\");
        for (String s : split) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }


    private static List<String> split(String s, String delimiter) {
        String[] split = s.split(delimiter);
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
            int[][] combinations = consecutiveCombinations(split.length, i);
            for (int[] combination : combinations) {
                 output.add(glue(split, combination, delimiter));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }


    private static String glue(String[] string, int[] indices, String delimiter) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0, indicesLength = indices.length; i < indicesLength - 1; i++) {
            int index = indices[i];
            stringBuilder.append(string[index]);
            stringBuilder.append(delimiter);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(string[indices[indices.length - 1]]);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static int[][] consecutiveCombinations(int n, int k) {
        int count = n - k + 1;
        int[][] output = new int[count][k];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int[] path = new int[k];
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                path[j] = i + j;
            }
            output[i] = path;
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
a
b
c
d
a\\b
b\\c
c\\d
a\\b\\c
b\\c\\d
```

Comment: @РусланИванов Outline: Generate all possible combinations of consecutive indices, then glue the corresponding strings together in a loop, and output those results in a list.

Comment: @ Blake How can i do it?

Comment: @РусланИванов The code above does exactly what you asked. You can do it by running that code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for you to consider.  This does the following:

- Iterates thru the numbers from `1` to `K` when `K` is the number of
  `2^ntokens -2`.  So for `a,b,c,d` the ntokens would be `4` and `K` would be `14`
- Then it finds those numbers which contain a single bit sequence of `1`
  bits.
- It then shifts thru those to determine which token should be included
  in the current substring.
- In the end it puts them in a list and returns.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      List<String> tokens = multiSplit("a\\b\\c\\d", "\\\\");
      tokens.forEach(System.out::println);

   }

   public static List<String> multiSplit(String val, String delim) {

      String[] sp = val.split(delim);

      // temp holding place for combinations
      List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();

      // Iterate from 1 to thru 2^ntokens - 1
      for (int n = 1; n < ((1 << sp.length) - 1); n++) {

         // Using BitSet, determine if n consists of a single string
         // of 1 bits.
         BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { (long) n
         });
         int[] indices = bitSet.stream().toArray();
         int len = indices.length - 1;

         // If the difference of the high indices equal the length of the
         // array minus 1, then a single stream has been found.
         if (len == indices[len] - indices[0]) {
            // create a substring of the source by using the bit positions.

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sp[indices[0]]);
            for (int k = 1; k < indices.length; k++) {
               sb.append(delim);
               sb.append(sp[indices[k]]);
            }
            vals.add(sb.toString());
         }
      }
      return vals;
   }
```

Comment: @РусланИванов  I have added another option for you to consider.  It also includes comments to describe how it works.